# Get JavaRdd from JavaDstream

Tags: java-8, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am building an web-app, where I am streaming twitter data into JavaDStream and then store these into kafka.I want to get JavaRdd from JavaDStream and store these Rdd's to kafka server. But I am not able to figure it out how to get the Rdd from the Dstream. Following is my code for refernce.

```
JavaDStream<String> statuses = twitterStream.map(
                new Function<Status, String>() {
                    public String call(Status status) { 
                        return status.getText();
                        }
                }
        );
```

Could anyone suggest a way?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can convert an DStream to RDD directly, instead you can try something like `foreachRDD` method see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaDStreamLike.html#foreachRDD(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2))
snippet from the link

`Apply a function to each RDD in this DStream. This is an output operator, so 'this' DStream will be registered as an output stream and therefore materialized.`